# reduction of that clause

Tags: grammar

"we know that they don't take excellent decisions that causes that the covid-19 ends"

"we know that they don't take excellent decisions causing the covid-19 ends"

in firs sentence, I want to reduce last "that clause" but I'm not sure whether it's correct

Comment: Neither sentence is valid syntax.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To begin with the initial sentence is not correct. You might write it that way instead.

- we know that they don't take the  decisions that would cause  the pandemia of covid-19 to end.

You can't use a that-clause with the verb "cause" ([ref.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/cause_2)).

[image].

Comment: There is no virus known *that causes* COVID-19 symptoms.  Perfectly valid syntax (even if the actual statement is nonsense).